# Best way to update data in a previous view controller in a UINavigationController stack

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a UINavigationController that adds muliple custom view controllers on top of it in its stack.

The first controller is a custom view controller that has a list of questions. Each question has a agree or disagree text with the count.

So the UI is like so:

```
What is question 1?
2 agree, 10 disagree

Who is this question 2?
3agrees, 0 disagress

and so on...
```

When a user clicks on the text for a question, the code does a pushViewController to the FullQuestionViewController. This controllers shows questions and comments. The user can also now click on the agree or disagree buttons.

Now once the user clciks agree/disagree, how do I just update the previous view controller counts? I want the counts to be updated when the user clicks on the

How is this accomplished?

Comment: Are you just using variables to store the answers or are you using Core Data?

Comment: Variables and Parse.com to store data.  Just curious how to update counts.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this code in FullQuestionViewController when you have to update to the new value . new_value is the value you want to update to.

`CustomViewController * custom = 
self.navigationController.viewControllers[self.navigationController.viewControllers.count -2] ;
custom.myCountVariableLabel.text = new_value  // new_value that should be update`

Comment: CustomViewController is the viewController which has the list of questions . myCountVariable is the variable which you use to show value. update the label according .